# NSMutableDictionary delete

Tags: objective-c, nsmutabledictionary

i used NSMutableDictionary for getting object and save it into the sqlite, then i show all the datas in tableView.. it is fine. while i deleting the particular row of the table, the data has been deleted successfully. but the memory space allocated to store that data was not clear. eg.. i have 5 datas in my database has the indexes from 1 to 5.. if i delete the 3rd and 4th data, it was deleted ok. but the indexes not get Re arranged.. it remains 1,2,5.. i want the indexes as 1,2,3 like that.. any one help me pls..

Comment: Can you include some code snippets to show us what you're trying to achieve please? Note that `NSMutableDictionary` is not an indexed data structure, it's a dictionary storing key/value pairs. Elements in the dictionary don't have an implicit index, so it sounds like you're storing those indexes as part of your key or value, in which case you wouldn't expect them to change as other elements in the dictionary are added, deleted or changed.

Answer (score 0):

`NSMutableDictionary` stores **keys** and **values**.

If you delete one pair of them, it won't effect the other other pairs - both keys and values stay as they are (it would be useless otherwise). Maybe you want to use `NSMutableArray` instead.